# Replace with sed until match in a line

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have to replace all "." characters before the "=" character in every line in a file.
The lines are like this:

```
one.two.three=something
four.five=1
six.seven=127.0.0.1
eight.nine.ten.eleven=somethingwerylong
twelve=something.with.dots
```

and so on...

The result must be like this:

```
onetwothree=something
fourfive=1
sixseven=127.0.0.1
eightnineteneleven=somethingwerylong
twelve=something.with.dots
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sed -e :1 -e 's/^\([^=]*\)\./\1/; t1'
```

`t1` branches to the `1` label if there has been a successful `s` command. That's one of the ways to implement conditional loops in `sed`.

Or:

```
awk -F = -v OFS== '{gsub(/\./, "", $1); print}'
```